# Xamarin Forms ActivityIndicator when starting app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I am a newbie to cross platform development and Xamarin Forms. My app takes about 5-6 seconds to load, meanwhile it has a white screen, I want to show the ActivityIndicator (or an image) instead of the white screen until it loads.

The first "activity" that loads is basic MainPage from demos
The XAML:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App2.Views"
        x:Class="App2.Views.MainPage">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MenuPage />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ItemsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

But I dont know where to put the `ActivityIndicator` (or image), if I put it in the constructor of `ItemsPage`, its already too late. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

added dependency for ACR User Dialogs and the line `UserDialogs.Init(this);` to my Android MainActivity.cs , still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a splash screen, for Android platform you must implement it manually in your Android project. Here is a very good tutorial [Xamarin.Forms (Android)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/oussamaalrifai/xamarin-forms-android-workaround-for-splash-screen-with-lo/)
And in iOS its built in, Just go to your iOS project, open info.plist file, in visual assets section set Launch Screen.

Comment: Thanx, that worked, any idea how to do the same on iOS?

Comment: Although I noticed the application sometimes exits at the SplashScreen with no error.

Comment: I'm using splash screen like that and it works without problems like this, Are you sure the problem is caused by splash screen?

Comment: I completed the answer for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this blog : "https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/" for adding splash screen in iOS and Android.

For your situation, splash screen should be the more suitable solution.